# Drag and Drop on a scaled container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, scale

I am new to React. I am working on a project, whose one of the features is dragging and dropping

The draggable components are supposed to be dragged and dropped on the container, say `A.container`, A also has the feature of zoom in and zoom out.

I have achieved this feature by changing its scale accordingly to achieve zoom in and zoom out. To achieve zoom in, I am multiplying the original scale which is 1 by 2. To achieve zoom out, I am dividing the current scale by 2.

The dropped component is dropped at the correct mouse position only when the scale is set to original. However, **when the scale has some different value. The component dropped is displayed far away from the mouse position.**

**How do I achieve correct drops at all other scales.**

Below is my code for the functionality.

Help would be appreciated

```
zoomIn = e => {
  if (this.state.scale == null) {
    this.setState({ scale: 1 });
  }
  this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale * 2 });
  console.log(this.state.scale);
  e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`;
  e.target.style.transformOrigin = "-0% -0%";
  console.log(this.state.scale);
  out = 0;
  console.log(e.target.style.transform);
  console.log(e.clientX);
  var dragtarget1 = document.getElementById("dragtarget1");
  console.log(dragtarget1.style.left);
  console.log(e.target.getBoundingClientRect().offsetX);
};
zoomOut = e => {
  this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale / 2 });
  console.log(this.state.scale);
  if (this.state.scale === 2.5) {
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(${(this.state.scale = null)})`;
    out = 1;
    this.cood();
  } else {
    out = 0;
  }
  console.log(this.state.scale);
  e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`;
  e.target.style.transformOrigin = "-0%,-0%";
};
drop = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
  event.target.appendChild(data);
  data.style.position = "fixed";
  data.style.left = (event.clientX - data.clientWidth / 2) / 2 + "px";
  data.style.top = (event.clientY - data.clientHeight / 2) / 2 + "px";

  //console.log(event.target.getBoundingClientRect())
  console.log(event);
  var dragtarget1 = document.getElementById("dragtarget1");
  setTimeout(function() {
    dragtarget1.classList.remove("hide");
  });
  var dragtarget2 = document.getElementById("dragtarget2");
  setTimeout(function() {
    dragtarget2.classList.remove("hide");
  });
  console.log(data.style.left);
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to explore react-dnd.

Comment: I'm not sure scale promises what you expect unless you scale up witdth and height.moreover your code uses native api like e.target.style, getElementById which is not the way to work with React.

Answer (score 1):

What if the object that you are trying to drop in Container A is scaled to the same transform properties as its destination container once you hover it over the destination container? (*before you drop it*)

Comment: I tried to set the scale of component  to that of the container on drop.But it didnt work.Only its size is getting changed

Comment: Hm ok.  If you are able to drop an item any where in the scaled container (not restricted to a grid), then another idea could be to use mouse coordinates while hovering the container, then use those coordinates upon drop to place the object with the scaled container.  I didn't create this CodeSandbox but here's a mouse coordinates example in react: https://codepen.io/CarlosEME/pen/XWWpVMp